# cannot resolve symbol clicker

Tags: android, android-spinner

im getting this error when trying to make spinner menu *Cannot Resolve Symbol "clicker"*

this is my code

```
package com.example.lizu;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.view.Menu;

import android.view.View;

import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

import android.widget.Button;

import android.widget.EditText;

import android.widget.Spinner;


public class Hitung extends Activity {

private Button Button;

private EditText EditText;

private Spinner Spinner;

String[] NilaiTukar = {

        "USD",

        "SGD",

        "EUR",

        "JPY",

        "HKD",

        "AUD",

        "GBP"

};

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.hitung);



    Spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

    Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nilaitukar);



    EditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);



    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,

            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, NilaiTukar);

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource

            (android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    Spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    Button.setOnClickListener(new clicker());

    OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {

            Spinner spnr = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

            EditText input = ( EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);

            EditText hasil = ( EditText) findViewById(R.id.hasil);

            String selectedItem = (String) spnr.getSelectedItem();

            if(selectedItem.trim().equals("USD")){

                double result = Integer.parseInt(input.getText().toString()) / 12783;

                hasil.setText(Double.toString(result));

            }else if(selectedItem.trim().equals("SGD")){

                double result = Integer.parseInt(input.getText().toString()) / 9599;

                hasil.setText(Double.toString(result));

            }else if(selectedItem.trim().equals("EUR")){

                double result = Integer.parseInt(input.getText().toString()) / 12000;

                hasil.setText(Double.toString(result));

            }else if(selectedItem.trim().equals("JPY")){

                double result = Integer.parseInt(input.getText().toString()) / 115;

                hasil.setText(Double.toString(result));

            }else if(selectedItem.trim().equals("HKD")){

                double result = Integer.parseInt(input.getText().toString()) / 1100;

                hasil.setText(Double.toString(result));

            }else if(selectedItem.trim().equals("AUD")){

                double result = Integer.parseInt(input.getText().toString()) / 9200;

                hasil.setText(Double.toString(result));

            }else if(selectedItem.trim().equals("GBP")){

                double result = Integer.parseInt(input.getText().toString()) / 14100;

                hasil.setText(Double.toString(result));

            }

        }

    };

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nilaitukar);

    btn.setOnClickListener(listener);

}

}
```

Comment: So what's the question? The error is pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: @Android777 im using android studio and on this statement ( Button.setOnClickListener(new clicker()); )
it say cannot resolve symbol clicker.

Comment: Well, this I can see, but do you actually have a class named `clicker` somewhere in the project?

Comment: no. but i has read on article they doesnt have a class on `clicker` and work. is it right? or i must add a `clicker` class?

Comment: I think (1) the article omitted `clicker` as they think it is pretty basic or (2) you missed the codes from that said article.

Answer (score 0):

[`Cannot Resolve Symbol {symbolname}`](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?CannotResolveSymbol) is pretty common error in Java. It means that the compiler was unable to find whatever `{symbolname}` is presented in the error.

In your case, I see that your code have:

```
Button.setOnClickListener(new clicker());
```

Now you need to check where do you store the `clicker` class definition.

Upon looking at your codes again I noticed that your line above is actually calling `setOnClickListener()` method from a class, on an instance of it. **I guess it is save to assume that that line is not needed. Can you comment it out and try your codes again?**